# What's the "right way" to access data in a .Net Core partial view in a layout?

Tags: asp.net-core, partial-views, dbcontext

I have a partial view called _SponsorPartial.cshtml being called in my _Layout.cshtml so that it's on every page:

```
    <footer>
        <div class="visible-xs-inline-block">
            @await Html.PartialAsync("_SponsorPartial")
        </div>
    </footer>
```

I'm using .Net core so I have my dbContext ready to be injected where I need it:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
       [...]
    }
```

_SponsorPartial is a Bootstrap carousel of images (database driven) based on a value that is different on different pages.  I could very easily build a function to get my list based on a parameter:

```
 public static List<SomeObject> GetObjects(int myParameter)
```

My initial thoughts were to access @ViewData["myParameter"] in the partial page, then have the partial page get the appropriate information from the function.

The issue is...How do I create a function in some class someplace that has access to the context objects?  Specifically ApplicationDbContext.  And how do I call it?!  In a controller I know I can inject ApplicationDbContext and pass it around...but this is a partial page...in a layout.

And the big question is of course...what is the "right" way to do this in an .Net Core (MVC) environment?  What is the right way to access database driven information from a partial view buried in a layout shown by almost every controller on the site.

Comment: usually you would create a viewmodel class that has the data you need, populate an instance of it in your controller action and pass it to the view

Comment: oops sorry, for layout, a good solution is implement a viewcomponent then you can inject anything into the viewcomponent that you need to build the viewmodel for the partial view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Joe said in the second comment, View Components exactly fit into your case. I tried to show how you can you implement it in your case.

First in _Layout change footer part like below:

```
<footer>
  <div class="visible-xs-inline-block">
     @Component.Invoke("SponsorComponent", ViewData["Parameter"])
  </div>
</footer>
```

And in pages(i supposed you have Page1, Page2):

Page1.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Page 1";
    ViewData["Parameter"] = <Parameter1>; 
}
```

Page2.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Page 2";
    ViewData["Parameter"] = <Parameter2>; 
}
```

Now,create a view model for component

```
public class SponsorViewModel
{
     // properties
}
```

Then, create Default.cshtml in the component folder(Views/Shared/Components/SponsorComponent/)

```
@model SponsorViewModel
 @* Compoent Content  *@
```

Finally, create View Component class:

```
[ViewComponent(Name = "SponsorComponent")]
public class SponsorViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
   private readonly DbContext _context; // if you want to inject dbcontext  
   public SponsorViewComponent(DbContext context)
   {
       _context = context;
   }
   public IViewComponentResult Invoke(object parameter)
   {
       var model =  new SponsorViewModel();
       // get data from db
       return View(model);
   }
}
```

Comment: That looks about right.  I'll need to learn some more about ViewComponents since that's a new concept for me.  What's the "Best Practice" folder to put a ViewComponent in...it's own folder?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what is the "best practice", but i put "ViewComponent class" inside "ViewComponets" folder. Default folder of cshtml file  is "Views\Shared\Components\{YourViewComponentName}\Default.cshtml"